# oci_bind_by_name not working in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, database-connection

Can anyone guide me on using oci_bind_by_name. I have written this piece of code:

```
$connection = initDB();
$validation_query = "SELECT * from admin where admin_id= :uid and password= :pwd";
$s = oci_parse($connection, $validation_query);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':uid', $id);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':pwd', $pass);
$res=oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);
$result_row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC);
```

But with slight modification to Code and generating the query on the fly, it starts working.

```
$connection = initDB();    
$validation_query = "SELECT * from admin where admin_id= '".$id."' and password= '".$pass."'";
$s = oci_parse($connection, $validation_query);
//oci_bind_by_name($s, ':uid', $id);
//oci_bind_by_name($s, ':pwd', $pass);
$res=oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);
$result_row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_BOTH);
```

I have no idea on this and have already searched forums and internet. Kindly help me out.

Comment: What doesn't work? What PHP and Oracle versions are you using?

Comment: oci_bind_by_name is not working that is the 1st piece of code is not working while the second one is.
PhP version 5.2 and Oracle10g

Comment: I get that oci_bind_by_name "doesn't work" - exactly *how* does it not work? does it produce an error, or does it work, but the query returns nothing, or the query returns an error, or .....

Comment: It works but the query returns nothing... No error messages are returned.

Comment: oci_bind_by_name returns 1 after execution

Comment: anyone.... who faced similar problems earlier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT !
Sorry to bother you guys... I made a silly mistake.

The line of code: `$result_row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_BOTH)`was being executed in both the codes. But in Second scenario `$result_row[0]` returned values where as  `$result_row[0]` fails in 1st scenario.

This is again because I was using different MODES of fetching data. OCI_ASSOC in first case and OCI_BOTH in second case.

So finally when I wrote  `$result_row['ID']`, I got the desired results.

Cheers !