# oci_fetch_array does not return expected column data in PHP

Tags: php

I'm retrieving table rows from a database. It looks like I'm successfully retrieving 1 row, but when I try to access that row, it ends up evaluating to nothing.

### Code

Note that I'm aware that there's an SQL-injection vulnerability in it, but that's not the main issue I'm interested in solving for this question:

```
<?php
include("core/connection.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

  $stid = oci_parse($conn,
    "SELECT CustomerNo FROM Customers WHERE Username = '" . $_POST['username']
    . "' AND Password = '" . $_POST['password'] . "'");

  oci_execute($stid);

  $count = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);
  echo "$count rows";

  $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM);
  echo $row['0'];

  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);
}
?>
```

### Results

When I do

```
echo "$count rows";
```

it shows 1 row, but when I do

```
echo $row['0'];
```

it returns nothing.

Comment: What does $row contain?

Comment: WOW! This select sounds really amazing. and UNSAFE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You should start from scratch... Use password hash for storing passwords I mean. And NEVER use POST data as it is. Verify post data first, and then if it is ok (no injection) try to make a query.

Comment: How does the query really look like? (echo query). What kind of result do you get when you copy the query directly in the database? (via phpmyadmin or something). print_r($row) to see what $row actually contains. Learn how to debug.

Comment: @Jacek Once their databases with about 100000 entries gets deleted by some 12 year old scriptkiddie who read a tutorial about SQLInjection, they will start to care about securing user input. ;)

Comment: Yeah. I think that three lines SQL - PHP tutorials should be really deleted from internet. This should help a lot with safety problems on let's say "small" websites :).

Comment: @user2656114 by the way, security is ALWAYS a concern ;). Sorry for exclamation marks, but this code is really a book example of "how not to do".

Comment: @Jacek: excessive consecutive exclamation/query marks is well known for inducing headaches, right up there with txtspk. I'm off for an aspirin, ouch!

Comment: OP, if you [know you have security vulns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630809/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injections-here) it's worth making a note of that in the question, so people know not to comment on that aspect. That helps conserve people's valuable time.

Comment: I have [asked a question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254810/how-to-deal-with-mob-voting) using this question as an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [oci\_bind\_by\_name not working in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921870/oci-bind-by-name-not-working-in-php)

Comment: Why do you concentrate on the security issues instead of answering the **REAL** question? He could've a system where security protection resides in another layer/piece of code.

Comment: @needaname it would be irresponsible for people to not comment on the security issue. Don't assume that people downvoted for that reason (that would unreasonable). Trust me, as discussed in [the Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254810/456814), there were other serious issues that were probably more a factor for prompting people to downvote.

Comment: @Cupcake I can see that now.

Comment: As of now the voting+rep pair system may be flawed and that's what I'm worried about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`oci_fetch_array()` with the `OCI_ASSOC` flag fetches an ***associative*** array, not an enumerated array.... this means that the array keys are the column names from your database query, not simply numbers

so `$row['CUSTOMERNO']` exists, `$row[0]` doesn't

see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php) for details

**EDIT**

Also, the fact that you are calling `oci_fetch_all()` initially means that you have already retrieved the complete resultset into `$res`, so when you call `oci_fetch_array()` the internal pointer is already at the end of the resultset so nothing further will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I switched to using `OCI_NUM` as this is what I want (I think). The `echo $count;` shows 1 rows but still `$row[]` returns nothing. Have I missed something in the process?

Comment: Well `oci_fetch_all()` has already fetched ___all___ the rows into $res, so there's no rows left to fetch using `oci_fetch_array()`

Comment: I would suggest editing into the answer the fact that the `oci_fetch_array` call is invalid since `oci_fetch_all` has already retrieved all the rows.